# error: value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, U)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to write the following method:

```
scala>   def isEqual[U, V](expected: RDD[U], result: RDD[V]) = {
 |         val expectedIndexValue: RDD[(Long, U)] = expected.zipWithIndex().map{ case (row, idx) => (idx, row) }
 |         val resultIndexValue: RDD[(Long, V)] = result.zipWithIndex().map{ case (row, idx) => (idx, row) }
 |         val combined = expectedIndexValue.join(resultIndexValue)
 |       }
```

But I got the following error:

```
<console>:52: error: value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, U)]
         val combined = expectedIndexValue.join(resultIndexValue)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The join function is defined on a special type called `PairRDDFunctions` and there is an implicit conversion between RDDs of tuples of this special type. If you are working in an old version of Spark you would need to import the implicit conversions e.g. `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`. There is also an explicit (albiet deprecated) function on the SparkContext called `rddToPairRDDFunctions` that you can manually use.

However both the explicit function and the implicit conversions require that the class tags for the types be present, so you could use a fake class tag, but since you're working in Scala you might as well just add the class tags as implicit params to your function.

Comment: you just answered at the same time as me, so he is running the Spark interpreter for Scala? Doesn't he need to call sc somewhere? Or is his approach sound? Happy to delete my answer if I am way off base thanks

Comment: Yah, thats the scala Syntax being used.

Comment: I see, but doesn't he need to make calls on sc somewhere to create an RDD in the first place?

Comment: Yah, at some point he would need to have used the spark context to create the RDD. However that part is not really related to the problem (and also if this was say being created for a library then its possible its simple getting passed in RDDs and the end user is the one who is expected to create the RDDs).

Comment: thanks for answering his question, I am gonna delete mine, sounds like I am way off thanks!